# Write ARIMA equation l from arima with drift output inR

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

i need to write the ARIMA equation  but i have a question about drift

```
fit = Arima(price, order = c(1,1,0),include.drift = TRUE)
```

These is result

```
  Series: price 
ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift 

Coefficients:
         ar1   drift
      0.3618  0.9272
s.e.  0.1452  1.2564

sigma^2 estimated as 34.55:  log likelihood=-161.74
AIC=329.49   AICc=330   BIC=335.28



z test of coefficients:

      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
ar1    0.36185    0.14518  2.4925  0.01269 *
drift  0.92723    1.25644  0.7380  0.46053  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

when hypothesis test with P-value 
the drift  is not significant

**Question**

When do I write ARIMA equation,I must write  drift in equation ?

Answer (score 0):

Standard arima software requires that the drift parameter MUST be included if there is no differencing incorporated otherwise it is optional. I have seen and used software where drift is ALWAYS an option.